# Javascript/jquery - how to make a textbox when hovering an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, textbox, hover

Im trying to build a website now but I ran into a problem.

How can I make a textbox appear when Im hovering over an image like in this picture below. Doestn have to be exactly like that, I just want a sort of textbox when Im hovering over an image.

Thanks in advance!

[image: textbox when hovering over an image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you want more than tool tip. This will have more styling and can be customized.

http://jsfiddle.net/NFH7H/1/

```
$('#test').mouseenter(function () {
   $('span').show();
});
```